# EF Core query optimization: can I use Contains on List<string>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core + .NET 5.0 preview + Postgres.

I am trying to find all questions with some tag.

I have this `Question` class:

```
public class Question : IEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// auto index
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
   //other properties       
}
```

So, I expected that this code would do what I want:

```
 var questions = _context.Questions
                         .Where(question => question.tags.Contains(tag) == true)
                         .AsQueryable();
return questions.AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

But nothing happens. I log the EF Core SQL query, it looks like this:

```
 [22:15:30 INF] Entity Framework Core 3.1.9 initialized 'ApplicationContext' using provider 
'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
 [22:15:30 INF] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
 SELECT q."Id", q."OwnerId", q.answer_count, q.bounty_amount, q.bounty_closes_date, q.closed_date, 
 q.closed_reason, q.content_license, q.creation_date, q.is_answered, q.last_activity_date, 
 q.last_edit_date, q.link, q.question_id, q.score, q.tags, q.title, q.view_count
 FROM "Questions" AS q
 WHERE (TRUE = FALSE) = TRUE
```

This query confused me.

I rewrote the code in a simpler way:

```
  var qResult = new List<Question>();
  var quests = _context.Questions.AsQueryable();

  foreach (var q in quests)
  {
      if (q.tags.Contains(tag))
          qResult.Add(q);
  }
```

This code works, but I'm afraid that it is not optimized query and when I will have more questions - I will lose memory.

So, how to do create an optimized query?

P.S. full code :  [github repo](https://github.com/LightVolk/QuestionServiceWebApi/blob/master/Db/Repository/EfCoreQuestionsRepository.cs)

And this is my `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
 }
 },
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Questions": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=questionsdb;Username=postgres;Password=password"
},
"Tags": [
  "ef core",
  "c#",
  "asp.net core",
  "asp.net core webapi"
  ]
 }
```

P.S.: another variant:

```
    var questions = _context.Questions.Where(question => question.tags.Contains(tag)).AsQueryable();
        return questions.ToList();


  [21:44:29 INF] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', 
  CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT q."Id", q."OwnerId", q.answer_count, q.bounty_amount, 
  q.bounty_closes_date, q.closed_date, q.closed_reason, q.content_license, 
  q.creation_date, q.is_answered, q.last_activity_date, q.last_edit_date, 
  q.link, q.question_id, q.score, q.tags, q.title, q.view_count
  FROM "Questions" AS q
  WHERE TRUE = FALSE
```

Comment: `public List<string> tags` is not mapped to any tables or columns - you can not use it the database query

Comment: @Fabio Actually it [is mapped to PostgreSQL array data type column](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) by its EF Core provider.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change your query to

```
        return   _context.Questions
                         .Where(q => q.tags.Contains(tag))
                         .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: but query will be same (withot ==true) like:WHERE TRUE = FALSE

Comment: Just try and  pls let me know the result.

Comment: Sorry I didn'  read the whole thing so I update my answer again. Maybe it looks the same but it is worthing to try. Nobody know how lInq compiler works.